# css - Borders with gradients

Tags: html, css

I've been stuck for a while trying to get this right:
[image: what i'm trying to get]

Notice that there is a gradient in the borders, I tried lots of things to get it done, nothing worked.
Any idea how can I get some kind of gradients like that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can try this tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Pretty useful, but I tried something alike the code it provides and didn't work as I wanted, thanks for the tool tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all its not gradient border, its the result of using box-shadow css property.

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #222;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 20px #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**box-shadow** property takes five arguments. The first one, when left, remains as outset. The second and third are for offset and forth and fifth are spread amount and color respectively.

```
box-shadow: inset/outset x y spread color;
```